TLS Certificate Verification Error
We have a WordPress website configured to send mail using smtp.office365.com via the WP Mail plugin, but can't currently send mail with SSL Verification enabled. Without verification, the email works showing that the mail account details (password etc.) are correct. The problem is the TLS Certificate validation. From debug output I can see that STARTTLS happens, but the handshake fails? What might cause this? Do specific ports need to be open? We have 587 outgoing open, do we need that incoming too? Everything else I can see externally suggests our certificates are correct (same cert used for HTTPs for example). What is blocking the verification?
A typical error looks like this:
Mailer: Other SMTP
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. Connection failed. stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failedSMTP server error: QUIT command failed
Debug Output:
Connection: opening to smtp.office365.com:587, timeout=300, options=array()
Connection: opened
SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 SY5PR01CA0072.outlook.office365.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Fri, 17 May 2024 01:16:02 +0000
CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO www.mydomain.com
SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-SY5PR01CA0072.outlook.office365.com Hello [myip]
250-SIZE 157286400
250-PIPELINING
250-DSN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-STARTTLS
250-8BITMIME
250-BINARYMIME
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8
CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 SMTP server ready
Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed [C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysite\wp-includes\PHPMailer\SMTP.php line 488]
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. Connection failed. stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
SERVER -> CLIENT:
SMTP ERROR: QUIT command failed:
Connection: closed
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. Connection failed. stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed


Might need to update openssl to a newer version perhaps. Ensure your logic calling the SMTP functions and such are using parameters to use starttls an/or secure or tls encryption on the SMTP connections. The cert should match DNS host name, be a wildcard of the domain, or have a valid SAN matching one of those. You aren't behind firewalls blocking or decrypting then re-encrypting SSL encrypted traffic as a proxy service like ssl inspection, correct?

@VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle Not sure about that....I'm a software dev looking at this from the website side...our IT guys looking at the other end. The system was working, and seems to have nosedived after we changed our firewall, even though (as far as we can tell) all rules from the old firewall were replicated to the new one.

Still don't really know what happened to break this, but we managed to fix it by creating an Office365 application in Azure and installing a new certificate on the server.
I did cobble together the PHP/CURL script below which was handy for connection diagnostics if it's useful to anyone.
<?php
    function read_cb($ch, $fp, $length) {
        return fread($fp, $length);
    }
    $url='smtp.office365.com:587';
    $out = fopen('php://temp', 'w+');
    
    $fp = fopen('php://temp', 'w+');
    $string = "From: <from@mydomain.com>\r\n";
    $string .= "To: <to@mydomain.com>\r\n";
    $string .= "Date: " . date('r') . "\r\n";
    $string .= "Subject: Test\r\n";
    $string .= "\r\n";
    $string .= "CURL Test From Website\r\n";
    $string .= "\r\n";
    fwrite($fp, $string);
    rewind($fp);

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,5);
    curl_setopt($ch,  CURLOPT_MAIL_FROM, '<from@mydomain.com>');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAIL_RCPT,  ['<to@mydomain.com>']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERNAME, 'smtp_username');
    curl_setopt($ch,  CURLOPT_PASSWORD, 'smtp_password');
    curl_setopt($ch,  CURLOPT_USE_SSL, CURLUSESSL_ALL);
    //curl_setopt($ch,  CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_1);
    curl_setopt($ch,  CURLOPT_INFILE, $fp);
    curl_setopt($ch,  CURLOPT_READFUNCTION, 'read_cb');
    curl_setopt($ch,  CURLOPT_UPLOAD , true);

    # This is where the settings to use verbose debugging are set
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $out);


    $data=(object)array(
        'response'  =>  curl_exec($ch),
        'status'    =>  curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE)
    );
    
    # To utilise the recorded verbose data rewind to the beginning and read the stream contents.
    rewind($out);
    $data->verbose=stream_get_contents($out);
   
    curl_close($ch);
    fclose($out);
        
    # to display the data in the console you need to make it Javascript friendly.
    # This pattern & replacement will replace newline characters to make it suitable for javascript multiline display.
    $pttn='@(\r\n|\n)@i';
    $repl='"+\'\n\'+"';
    
    # We need to also remove double quotes from output response - replace with single quotes before calling preg_replace.
    $status=$data->status;
    $verbose=str_replace('"',"'", $data->verbose );

    printf('<script>console.info("Status code:%s\n\nVerbose output:\n%s")</script>', $status, preg_replace(
        $pttn,
        $repl,
        $verbose
    ));
?>

